# AdWords Remarketing javascript (conversion_async.js) is not loading

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

Per the [Google Asynchronous AdWords Remarketing tag instructions](https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/asynchronous/#standard-javascript-use) I add the following snippet inside the head section of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But I'm unable to call the google_trackConversion function after page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
window.google_trackConversion({
  google_conversion_id: 123456789, 
  google_custom_params: {
    parameter1: 'abc123', 
    parameter2: 29.99
  },
  google_remarketing_only: true
});
//]]>
</script>
```

However if copy/paste the code from conversion_async.js to the head section it works just fine, indicating the conversion_async.js file is not loading from the googleadservices.com server.

How can I ensure the conversion_async.js file has already been loaded before calling google_trackConversion?

(BTW, as suggested someplace else I toggled AddBlock Plus on/off but that doesn't have any effect)

Comment: I seem to have found the problem. I'm using SSL, but the snippet supplied by Google uses "http". I simply changed it to "https" and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set the onload callback which executes window.google_trackConversion() for the script tag
`<script type="text/javascript" onload="callback()" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: Thanks @chinhung, but as noted in my comment to my question up top, the problem was simply using "http" as opposed to "https".